# Optimizing pointer copies in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization

So today I was trying to optimize linked list traversal today. My thought was the it's less efficient to copy cur to last and then next to cur, when I could just do one copy. Hopefully the code below helps make it clearer:

```
struct Node{
    int body;
    Node* next;
};

Node* construct(int len){
    Node *head, *ptr, *end;
    head = new Node();
    ptr = head;
    ptr->body = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<len; i++){
        end = new Node();
        end->next = NULL;
        end->body = i;

        ptr->next = end;
        ptr = end;
    }
    return head;
}

int len(Node* ptr){
    int i=1;
    while(ptr->next){
        ptr = ptr->next;
        i += 1;
    }
    return i;
}

void trim(Node* head){
    Node *last, *cur;
    cur = head;
    while(cur->next){
        last = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    last->next = NULL;
}

void tumble_trim(Node* head){ // This one uses less copies per traverse
    Node *a, *b;
    a = head;
    while(true){
        if(!a->next){
            b->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
        b = a->next;
        if(!b->next){
            a->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
        a = b->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    int start;
    Node *head;

    start = clock();
    head = construct(100000);
    for(int i=0; i<5000; i++){
        trim(head);
    }
    cout << clock()-start << endl;

    start = clock();
    head = construct(100000);
    for(int i=0; i<5000; i++){
        tumble_trim(head);
    }
    cout << clock()-start << endl;
}
```

The results however were quite surprising to me. In fact the one with less copies was slower:

```
1950000
2310000 // I expected this one to be faster
```

Can anyone explain why the tumble_trim() function is so slow?

Comment: Have you compiled this benchmark in Release? Also, please note that in general, `clock()` is a terrible function for measuring performance-sensitive code (it's only accurate to within ~15ms). And for micro-optimizations like this, you should take a look at the generated assembly code!

Comment: Your `trim` and `tumble_trim` functions can fail badly on a list of length 1.

Comment: That `while(cur->next)`... I don't think that syntax is valid. Perhaps you mean `while(cur->next != 0)`?

Comment: @asrivat1 No, that's valid.

Comment: In release mode I get the opposite. Respectively, 1,109,365 and 922,552

Comment: @Cameron is correct - look at the assemply. The first method should boil down to swapping some registers, while the second will likely involve memory lookups.

Comment: @asrivat1: Nothing wrong with that whatsoever.

Comment: Not sure why you think two branches is going to be less expensive than one pointer copy. Even if you'd actually eliminated one pointer copy. Which you haven't.

Comment: Why do you think there are less "pointer copy" ?

Comment: Your benchmark includes the construction time. That doesn't make sense when you want to measure only trim.

Comment: It is not copying of pointers that makes linked list traversal slow. It is the lack of memory locality. If you want performance, don't use linked lists.

Answer (score 3):

You compiler is obviously optimising `trim()` much more than it can `tumble_trim()`.  It's a prime example of keeping your code simple and readable and *only* trying *any* optimisation after you've identified a bottleneck through performance analysis.  And even then you'll be hard pressed to beat the compiler on a simple loop like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant parts of the generated assembly for the two functions: (just the while loops:

trim:

```
LBB2_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movq    %rcx, %rax
    movq    %rdi, %rcx
    movq    8(%rdi), %rdi
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    jne LBB2_1
## BB#2:
```

tumbletrim:

```
LBB3_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movq    8(%rax), %rdx
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  LBB3_2
## BB#3:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB3_1 Depth=1
    movq    8(%rdx), %rdi
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    movq    %rdx, %rcx
    jne LBB3_1
## BB#4:
    movq    $0, 8(%rax)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
LBB3_2:
```

Now, let's try to describe what happens in each:

In trim, the following steps are performed:

1. copy 3 pointer-sized values
2. test the condition for the while loop
3. if the condition is satisfied, jump to the beginning of the loop

In other words, each iteration contains 3 copies, 1 test and 1 jump instruction.

Now, your clever optimized tumbletrim:

1. copy 2 pointer-sized values
2. test the condition for the break
3. if the condition is satisfied, jump to the end of the loop
4. else copy a pointer-sized value
5. test the condition for the while loop
6. copy a pointer-sized value
7. jump to the beginning of the loop

In other words, in the *final* iteration, when you exit the loop, the total number of instructions executed is:

- trim: 3 pointer copies, 1 compare
- tumbletrim: 2 pointer, 1 compare, 1 jump

In all other iterations, the total count looks as follows:

- trim: 3 pointer copies, 1 compare, 1 jump
- tumbletrim: 4 pointer copies, 2 compares, 1 jump

So in the rare case (the last iteration before exiting the loop), your implementation is cheaper *if and only if* a jump instruction is cheaper than copying a pointer-sized value from register to register (which it is not)

In the common case (all other iterations, your implementation has more copies *and* more compares. (And more instructions, putting more load on the instruction cache. And more branch statements, putting more load on the branch cache)

Now, if you're at all concerned about performance *in the first place*, then there are two much more fundamental things you're doing wrong:

1. you are using a linked list. Linked lists are slow because of the algorithm they perform (which involves jumping around in memory, because the nodes are not allocated contiguously), and not because of the implementation. So no matter how clever your implementation is, it would not compensate for the underlying algorithm being terrible
2. you are writing your own linked list. If you absolutely *must* use a linked list, use the one that was written by experts (`std::list`)

Comment: One iteration of tumble trim moves two nodes along the linked list instead of one though.